# "show more" button on gallery for mobile only - pure CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I create a “Show All” button after the first image in the gallery on mobile - 600px<, and have a scrollable fixed-width block (div) everywhere else?

It seems, that the only way to do it without js is to have either one or the other - either "Show more" button, or a fixed-width scrollable section.

```css
     
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 1200px;
      padding: 0 1rem;
    }
    .book {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    .cell img {
      display: block;
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      .container{
        overflow: auto;
        height: calc(70vh);
      }
      .grid {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
      }
      .cell {
        width: calc(50% - 2rem);
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
      .container{
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 80vh;
      }
      .cell {
        width: calc(33.3333% - 2rem);
      }
    }
    
    .cell {
      margin: 1rem;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container" id="books">
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="grid">
        
        <div class="cell">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" class="book">
         </div>
            
        <div class="cell">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" class="book">
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" class="book">
        </div>
         <div class="cell">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" class="book">
        </div>
         <div class="cell">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" class="book">
        </div>
         <div class="cell">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" class="book">
        </div>
         <div class="cell">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" class="book">
        </div>
         <div class="cell">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300" class="book">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
      </div>
```

Comment: use `media-queries` to make `div` none or block using `media-queries`

Comment: I tried that, and it worked on mobile, but than on any device bigger than defined 600px it would either ruin the gallery, or worse - disappear and hide all content apart from the first image

Comment: I’d suggest you ween yourself off of the idea that it was “always better” to do such things purely in CSS … because many times, it is actually not, and the usability of such solutions is questionable.